# Angular 2 RC6 PrimeNG p-dropdown not getting disabled from component

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am trying to disable the PrimeNg drop down on page initialization as follows

```
    this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       dropdown: [{value: '', disabled: true}]   
    });
```

But this gives an error on browser load as follows:

```
this.valueAccessor.setDisabledState is not a function
```

I am using PrimeNG drop down in HTML as follows:

```
       <p-dropdown  [options]="[{label: 'Any', value: ''},{label: 'Active', value: 'active'},{label: 'Inactive', value: 'inactive'}]" id="dropdown" formControlName="dropdown" name="dropdown">
      </p-dropdown>
```

Not sure if PrimeNg is not supporting this change from angular or I am doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be supported in PrimeNG beta 16.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. Marking your answer correct because got the same info from PrimeNG Community Forum.

Comment: It is implemented now -> https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/883

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
 <div class="ui-g-2 labelDiv">
      <p-dropdown [disabled]="disabled" [options]="themesList" formControlName="theme" (onChange)="onThemeSelect()"></p-dropdown>
 </div>
```

Component:

```
disabled: Boolean;
this.themeForm = this.fb.group({
   theme: [{ value: theme, disabled: true}, [], ]
});
```

This works fine in my app.... RC6 primeNg beta15...

Comment: thanks John for prompt reply. But i tried this and it gives a warning below.

          'It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
      when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
      you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.'

Comment: I amended my answer after testing your proposal.  I got the same error you did using [disable] in the html, but the proposed solution in the error message worked just fine for me.

Comment: No luck, Still getting the error message "this.valueAccessor.setDisabledState is not a function"

Comment: what version of angular and priming?

Comment: Angular RC6 and PrimeNG 1.0.0-beta.15